# Positioning one div to the right of another

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and css. But what I can't figure out is how to have the tabs div at the right of the main div. So that they stick out the right like bookmarks.

```
.main {
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    height: 75%;
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    right: auto;
  }
.tabs {
    width: 50px;
    height: 1.3em;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
 #tab { margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="content">
       Some main content
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tabs">
     <div class="tabs" id="tab1">
         <a href="#" alt="Home">
             Home
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs" id="tab2">
          <a href="#" alt="About">
              About
          </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique--make #tab into .tab to prevent problems down the line. Also, anchors don't have alt attributes. Try title instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two general approaches to putting blocks left to right:

1. Make them inline; or
2. Use floats.

(1) would be:

```
div.main, div.tabs { display: inline; }
```

(2) would be:

```
div.main, div.tabs { float: left; }
```

If you do (2) put the divs in a container and add:

```
div.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

Each method has particular merits. Most notably `inline` elements can't have `margin` attributes applied to them. This is just one of the several constraints on inline vs block layout in HTML.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. It doesn't show the container or its contents at all. I have pasted everything because perhaps the problem is beyond what I have posted: http://pastebin.ws/6v9lft